# как работает нижнее подчёркивание в javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, return

```
function isSorted(arr) {
  const limit = arr.length - 1;
  return arr.every((_, i) => (i < limit ? arr[i] <= arr[i + 1] : true));
}
```

Функция работает, как я её понимаю и не понимаю:

1. `i<limit` говорит нам, дошли мы до конца массива или нет, если дошли, то выводит, что массив отсортирован (true), если же не дошли, то переходит на следующий элемент массива
2. `arr[i] <= arr[i + 1]`
3. `arr.every` проверяет, прошли ли все элементы массива установленное условие
4. а что делает `(_, i) =>`

Прошу ответить на 4-ый пункт как можно более понятнее, я примерно представляю, что тут происходит, но ещё не совсем, было бы хорошо показать, каким куском кода можно заменить код в пункте 4.
И если я ошибся в объяснении других пунктов, тоже прошу исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Дополнил ответ подробней

Comment: К ответам ниже, можно еще добавить именно про символ подчеркивания. Не редко, таким образом обозначают аргумент, который должен присутствовать, например, в случае предписанного синтаксисом порядка, но в самом сценарии не принимает участия. Метод `every` принимает первым аргументом текущий обрабатываемый элемент массива, но для задачи  нужен был только второй аргумент  - индекс этого элемента. Без первого аргумента, второй не получим. Поэтому, автор кода обозначил первый, как "незначащий" символом подчеркивания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"_" - это просто символ, ничем не отличающийся от других

> а что делает `(_, i) =>`

В данном случае "_" - это текущий элемент массива, передаваемый в callback-функцию, i - его индекс

```
arr.every((_, i) => (i < limit ? arr[i] <= arr[i + 1] : true));
```

В данном случае перебирается весь массив и проверяется, что текущий элемент меньше или равен следующему. Т.е. массив отсортирован. Когда кончаются элементы, то возвращается true

> Метод every() вызывает переданную функцию callback один раз для каждого элемента, присутствующего в массиве до тех пор, пока не найдет такой, для которого callback вернет ложное значение (значение, становящееся равным false при приведении его к типу Boolean). Если такой элемент найден, метод every() немедленно вернёт false. В противном случае, если callback вернёт true для всех элементов массива, метод every() вернёт true. Функция callback вызывается только для индексов массива, имеющих присвоенные значения; она не вызывается для индексов, которые были удалены или которым значения никогда не присваивались.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1):

Подчеркивание в JavaScript не имеет никаких "магических свойств". Просто автор так назвал параметр анонимной функции.

Метод `every` вызывает для каждого элемента масива переданную ему функцию. Переданная функция может принимать до 3 параметров - `ЗначениеТекущегоЭлемента`, `ПорядковыйНомерЭтогоЭлемента`, и `ПеребираемыйМасив`. В качестве результата эта фунция должна вернуть `true` или `false`. Если все вызовы переданной функции вернут `true` - `every` вернет `true`. Если хоть один вызов вернет `false` - `every` вернет `false`.

Если использовать обычный цикл, то аналогичный код будет выглядить так:

```
function isSorted(arr) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 ; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( arr[i] > arr[i+1] )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно упростить ф-ю:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [3, 2, 1]

function isSorted (arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).every((item, i) => arr[i] >= item)
}

console.log(isSorted(arr), isSorted(arr2))
```

Если надо циклом:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
const arr2 = [3, 2, 1]

function isSorted (arr) {
  for (let i in arr.slice(1))
    if (arr[i - 1] < arr[i])
      return false 
  return true
}

console.log(isSorted(arr), isSorted(arr2))
```